# Что такое Dot11?

Tags: python, wifi, scapy

Недавно захотел понять как работают Wifi Jammer'ы на python и нашел пакет который отправляется жертве:

```
pkt = RadioTap()/Dot11(addr1=ap, addr2=client, addr3=client)/Dot11Deauth()
```

Хочу узнать что такое `Dot11`,`Dot11Deauth`?

Answer (score 1):

`Dot11` это класс библиотеки на питоне, который описывает данные, соответствующие стандарту `802.11`. В этом месте подставляется адрес точки доступа, адрес приёмника и адрес клиента, на которого производится атака.

`Dot11Deauth` это класс описывающий сообщение о разрыве wifi соединения, который с помощью перегрузки оператора `/` помещается в пакет сообщения 802.11, дальше добавляются заголовки драйвера Radiotap. Сформированный пакет можно отправить в radiotap устройство - в wifi адаптер в режиме мониторинга.